# Call webservice and get response using its URL

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have web service URL http://matrixrets.abor.com/rets/login.ashx and http://matrixrets.abor.com/rets/getobject.ashx?Resource=Property&Type=Photo&ID=195850:0

I am not able to add web reference in project due to login and it gives discovery error (value cannot be null).

How to directly pass credential using web service url using code instead of adding web reference?

I am fetching image using below code.. and it gives error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." even if I am passing credentials.

```
string url = "http://matrixrets.abor.com/rets/getobject.ashx?Resource=Property&Type=Photo&ID=195850:0";
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "***");
            byte[] image = webClient.DownloadData(url);
```

Comment: .ashx files are Generic Handler, not web services. For web service it ends with .asmx. Have a look at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
for more details.

Comment: Ok, So how can I call http://matrixrets.abor.com/rets/getobject.ashx?Resource=Property&Type=Photo&ID=195850:0 URL using username password?

Comment: Any update on my question?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/871179/en-us